# converting connect by prior query to WITH

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to convert a query that uses connect_by_root and connect by prior to eliminate the connect by prior. The original query is

```
SELECT   distinct CONNECT_BY_ROOT user.userid AS userid ,     
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT user.username USERNAME,     
    gr.BALANCE,
    client.agentid , 
    gr.closedt
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN GAMEGROUP gr  ON (gr.userid= user.userid)  
    WHERE gr.closedt>= to_date('1/2/2014 0:0','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') and  gr.closedt<= to_date('10/2/2014 23:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')    
    START WITH user.agentid      IS NULL     CONNECT BY PRIOR  user.userid=user.agentid ;
```

I've converted the query to

```
WITH r (USERID, USERNAME, BALANCE, AGENTID, PARTITIONDATE) AS
(SELECT distinct CONNECT_BY_ROOT user.userid AS userid,     
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT user.username USERNAME,     
    gr.BALANCE,    
    user.agentid , 
    gr.closedt
     FROM client   
    LEFT JOIN GAMEGROUP gr  ON (gr.userid= user.userid)  
    WHERE gr.closedt>= to_date('1/2/2014 0:0','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') and  gr.closedt<= to_date('10/2/2014 23:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct CONNECT_BY_ROOT cl.userid AS userid,     
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT cl.username USERNAME,     
    g.BALANCE,
    cl.agentid ,
    g.closedt
    FROM r, user cl
    LEFT JOIN BACKOFFICE.GAMEGROUP g  ON (g.userid= cl.userid)  
    WHERE g.closedt>= to_date('1/2/2014 0:0','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') and  g.closedt<= to_date('10/2/2014 23:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') AND r.userid=cl.agentId)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

I'm getting an error ORA-01788 CONNECT BY clause required in this query block. Does anyone see the problem in my new query please?

Comment: I think the problem is related to the CONNECT_BY_ROOT as i've been able to convert other queries which don't use it but I don't understand why it is causing an error or how to fix it

Comment: As the error says, you can only use `connect_by_root` with a `connect by` - what do you expect it to mean otherwise?

Comment: As I said i suspected that was the problem but I'm still new to hierarchical queries and not sure how to replace the connect_by_root.